# How to install libQtGui.so.4 32bit on 64bit ubuntu

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to compile the android tree on Ubuntu 64bit 12.04; The build fails on an error of missing shared library libQtGui.so.4;

Check /usr/ lib files i found that: /usr/lib/ or /usr/lib32 doesn't have Qt. /usr/lib/x86_64_xxxxx/libQutGui.so.4 does exist.

The package is already installed; however, i believe the installed version is 64bit while the build requires i386 (32bit) version;

how can i install the i386 version of libQt?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I ran 32-bit software on a 64-bit system.

```
ldd xxx
libQtGui.so.4 => not found
libQtCore.so.4 => not found
```

Then I installed [libqtgui4:i386 [image: Install libqtgui4:i386]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqtgui4).

```
apt-get install libqtgui4:i386
ldd xxx
libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xf67e3000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xf64dc000)
```

https://www.slsknet.org/news/node/482

Comment: @Glorfindel Your edit attaches a link different from that of OP's link while the original [link](https://snapcraft.io/)isn't damaged, is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

To compile software against the 32-bit version of Qt 4, you will need to install the `libqt4-dev:i386` package. This will remove the 64-bit version, but it can be re-installed after, if you need to compile 64-bit software later.

Answer (score -1):

This is it:

```
apt-get purge qt5-default -y
apt-get purge qt5-qmake -y
apt-get purge qtbase5-dev-tools -y
apt-get purge qttools5-dev-tools -y
apt-get install gcc-4.9 -y
apt-get install qt5-default -y
apt-get install qt5-qmake -y
apt-get install qtbase5-dev-tools -y
apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools -y
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and explain *why* the individual `apt-get`s actually help?  **;-)** *For the record: I didn't downvote your answer, but am willing to upvote if you expand it a little and drop me a note @Fabby.*